# Silverlight Event Handlers Respond Extremely Slow

Tags: c#, silverlight, event-handling

I am creating a dynamic hexgrid, 8 columns of 10 hexes, with an ellipse centered in random hexes.

I had originally thought the event handlers were not loading. It now appears they are loading, but are reacting very slowly. As I mouse over the generated grid after a minute or two, the hexes start randomly filling and the tooltips start showing (but not until the event handler for that hex responds). It actually takes several minutes for the last hex to respond to the mouseover event.

```
     private void CreateHexGrid(int columns, int rows, double length)
    {
       //I create a jagged array of points, 
       //hexpoint[# of columns, # of rows, 6 points]
       //the base (0,0) hex is generated point by point 
       //mathematically based on the length of one side 
       //then each subsequent hex is mathematically
       //created based on the points of the previous hex.
       //Finally, I instantiate each Polygon hex and fill 
       //its points collection using the array.
              PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
              SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
              SolidColorBrush clearBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
              Polygon hex = new Polygon();
              hex.Stroke = blackBrush;
              hex.StrokeThickness = 1;
              hex.Name = "Hex" + column.ToString() + row.ToString();

              for (int point = 0; point < 6; point++)
               {
                  points.Add(HexPoint[column, row, point]);
               }

              hex.Points = points;
              ToolTipService.SetToolTip(hex, hex.Name);
              hex.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(hex_MouseEnter);
              cnvsHexGrid.Children.Add(hex);
       //....
     }
```

Currently I have the handler simply trying to change the fill color of the polygon/ellipse to test. I would eventually like to generate an interactive pop-up window if a hex is clicked on.

```
    void hex_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hex = sender as Polygon;
        SolidColorBrush blueFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        hex.Fill = blueFill;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong to cause such slow, slow, slow reaction?

Comment: As a follow-up, if I comment out the event handler, the tool-tips cease to function regardless of how long I wait.  I have tested this in several browsers and the outcome is the same

Answer (score 0):

Adding a handler in the Load_Main seemed to help clear this up.